# Gradle / groovy setting up environment variables

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am facing some problems setting up environment on windows command prompt:

What I am doing:

1. Setting up environment (create environmental variables)
2. Run bat after configuring environment

I tried two different approaches:

1. Creating two different tasks on build.gradle:

> ```
> task setupenvironment(type:Exec) 
> {
>      def DirLocation = 'C:/../path/'
>      workingDir = new File(DirLocation)
>      commandLine DirLocation + 'environment.cmd'
>         args =  [ '-x',       location,
>                   '-y',           WorkspaceLocation,
>                   '-z',           'generated'
>           ]
> }
> task createwithpackage (type:Exec, dependsOn: setupenvironment) 
> {
>      def DirLocation = 'C:/../path/'
>      def WorkspaceLocation = 'C:/../Workspace'
>      def location = 'C:/../location'
>      workingDir = new File(DirLocation)
>      commandLine DirLocation + 'package.bat'
>         args =  [ '-x',       location,
>                   '-y',           WorkspaceLocation,
>                   '-z',           'generated'
>           ]
> }
> ```

```
//console: gradle createwithpackage --stacktrace
ERROR -> Process 'command 'C:/../package.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 255
```

2. Creating task on build.gradle to call .bat which has both processes

> ```
> task createall(type:Exec) { 
> {
>      def DirLocation = 'C:/../'
>      workingDir = new File(DirLocation)
>      commandLine DirLocation + 'deploy.bat'
> }
> task createwithpackage(type:Exec) { 
> {
>      def DirLocation = 'C:/../path/'
>      def WorkspaceLocation = 'C:/../Workspace'
>      workingDir = new File(DirLocation)
>      commandLine DirLocation + 'package.bat'
>         args =  [ '-x',       location,
>                   '-y',           WorkspaceLocation,
>                   '-z',           'generated'
>           ]
> }
> ```

deploy.bat

> ```
> CALL "C:\..\ environment.cmd" 
> CALL gradle createwithpackage
> ```

```
//console: gradle createall –stacktrace
Exception throwed: createwithpackage: Could not find or load main class com.package.class
```

However, if I execute above commands manually within the console, everything works fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

--EDIT

Sorry for replying so late, I tried before as suggested on your link. However I was having all the time this error, and I debug and use stacktrace for looking the problem, finally I got it work but only for one task

This work only for a direct task (No setting up environment variables before task):

> ```
> task createwithpackage (type:Exec) 
> {
>      def DirLocation = 'C:/../path/'
>      def WorkspaceLocation = 'C:/../Workspace'
>      def location = 'C:/../location'
>      workingDir = new File(DirLocation)
>      commandLine DirLocation + 'package'
>         args =  [ '-x',       location,
>                   '-y',           WorkspaceLocation,
>                   '-z',           'generated'
>           ]
> }
> ```

However next approach, starts well but at the end when it tries to save on disk, throws an expection 'Access denied' so I am guessing it has to be something with gradle privileges which I am not sure how to manage (I am running cmd as administrator with all privileges):

> ```
> task createwithpackage (type:Exec) 
> {
>      def DirLocation = 'C:/../path/'
>      def WorkspaceLocation = 'C:/../Workspace'
>      def location = 'C:/../location'
>      workingDir = new File(DirLocation)
>      commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'package', '-x', location '-y', WorkspaceLocation, '-z', 'generated'
> }
> ```

//gradle createwithpackage --debug

```
09:27:57.640 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully
 started process 'command 'cmd''
09:29:06.193 [QUIET] [system.out] BIP0963E Error saving file in createwithpackage.
09:29:06.203 [QUIET] [system.out]
09:29:06.213 [QUIET] [system.out] The file "C:\path..\main
/" could not be saved to disk.
09:29:06.223 [QUIET] [system.out] The reason given was:
09:29:06.223 [QUIET] [system.out] C:\path..\main (Access i
s denied.)
09:29:06.233 [QUIET] [system.out]
09:29:06.233 [QUIET] [system.out]
09:29:09.483 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing st
ate to: FAILED
09:29:09.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'co
mmand 'cmd'' finished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)
09:29:09.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceT
askExecuter
```

Is there anyway to let gradle with full privileges? Any further help will be appreciate

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute it as a [cmd in the Exec task](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html):

```
commandLine 'cmd', '/c', DirLocation + 'deploy.bat'
```

Comment: I tried this approach before, I edited my question with further information